# ServerSelectionTimeoutError on connecting mongo atlas cluster, while importing mongo db data on azure machine learning studio

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to import data to Azure Machine Learning experiment using MongoDB database from mongoAtlas.

So for that I used Python script using Pymongo library to connect to my MongoDB host. I'm getting an error like:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster-shard-00-.....mongodb.net:27017: ('The write operation timed out',)Process returned with non-zero exit code 1---------- End of error message from Python interpreter ---------- Process exited with error code -2
```